# What data can a VPN provider get when analyzing HTTPS traffic without hacking?

Tags: vpn

What can VPN providers see without hacking when I access an email site (ex. mail.yahoo.com) with HTTPS via their service? Can they see only not critical data like source and destination IP's, timestamp etc. or can they see more detailed information like my email address which I access on this page?

Comment: There's this thing called DPI and it's truly scary: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_packet_inspection Lately it's been used with AI which makes it even scarier. I don't claim it can reveal your email address but it can uniquely identify your traffic patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can see the equivalent of the post office looking at a box mailed to you. Post can see the origin, destination, size, weight, and nothing more.

VPN provider can see origin (your IP), destination domain and IP, destination port, duration, and how much bytes you sent and received. No other information can be seen.

They can know you are using Yahoo Mail, but nothing on how many accounts you have, if you have one account or ten, what your email are, how many emails you received, nothing like that. Only that on a given date and time you spent 30 minutes sending and receiving data from Yahoo Mail, and that amounted to 150MB.

Comment: Thank you for answer. So they CAN NOT see my email address which I access on mail's service page if I using HTTPS? Am I right?

Comment: Correct. They cannot see your email.

Comment: They could see the URLs though, and the query string may leak some telling data.

Comment: No, they cannot see the URL. Only the host because of the SNI (Server Name Indicator). The query string is encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

Any data delivered over HTTPS (TLS) will be hidden from the VPN provider as well as any other network that traffic travels through. So, any content or the specific page you visit will be hidden.

Anything not sent over HTTPS is in the clear and any network, like a VPN, can read it.

The VPN provider needs the TCP/IP network information in order to send your traffic.

Comment: Thank you for answer. So they CAN NOT see my email address which I access on mail's  service page if I using HTTPS? Am I right?

Comment: @NS0144 Correct, the VPN provider would see the IP you are communicating with and or the Domain name you are communicating with but the url path and http data are encrypted.  At most they could track how much data was sent / received over a given period of time.